# React document upload with plupload

Tags: reactjs, plupload

Sorry if this is already been asked and covered in another question.

We are looking forward to implement multi-part document upload (including drag and drop feature) in react web application using plupload library. Planning to reuse existing document service for upload.
I could not find any NPM package of Plupload which i can integrate with my react application.

Do we need to consider wrapper to integrate Plupload.

Also, please suggest, if we should consider any other library, incase plupload does not support it?

Kindly suggest. Thank you in advance.

UPDATE -

1. We are using Drag zone for UI integration
2. May need to see, how we can implement chunking logic while hitting document service.
   a. We are thinking can we use FileReader from Mozilla developers.
   b. May need to see, if we can use any wrapper for service integration.

Thanks, please suggest if you have any suggestion.

3.

Comment: There are several React JS libraries you can use for file upload. Check the link here
https://morioh.com/p/a5ee5f3bcbc8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this library to use the functionalities of Pulpload in react

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-plupload
```

Comment: will it have, drag and drop feature as well?